# How to concate dynamic variable names?

Tags: php

i am trying this very basic data to pass sql value in php variable so that based on mysql data its dynamic

```
     $lang_.$cus_no='selected=\"selected\"';
```

this $cus_no is coming from sql which changes and its number so i want to pass $lang_10 ='selected=\"selected\"'; 
this 10 in last will change as per data received from sql but the problem i am facing is 
instead of passing

```
     $lang_10='selected=\"selected\"';
```

it passes this 'selected=\"selected\"'; only to $cus_no variable

any help will be great. i have tried different combination of  single quote double quote , escape but its not working.

Comment: Variable variables are almost never the proper solution - use arrays instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct syntax to concate variable names.

Use `${"someName" . $someValue}` or `$$StringThatContainsTheVariableName`

For example :

```
<?php
$cus_no = 10;
${"lang_" . $cus_no} = "foo";

echo $lang_10;
```

This outputs :

> foo

---

Another way to do :

```
<?php
$cus_no = 10;
$VariableName = "lang_" . $cus_no;

// notice the $$
$$VariableName = "foo";

echo $lang_10;
```

This outputs :

> foo